# Superscript characters are resulting in to junk characters in generated CSV file when using ICsvListWriter

Tags: csv, special-characters, superscript, supercsv, unicode-escapes

I am trying to write superscript characters in .csv file. I am using method `write(List<?> columns)`of org.supercsv.io.ICsvListWriter. In generated .csv file the superscript character is coming along with junk character before it.

```
List columns = new ArrayList();
String myString = "abcd1";
columns.add(myString.replaceAll("1", "¹"));
csvWriter.write(columns);
```

In the generated .csv file it is coming as

```
abcdÂ¹
```

I also tried with unicode but it is not helping.

```
columns.add(myString.replaceAll("1", "\u00B9"));
```

Any suggestion here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for this problem. Correction was needed in creating ICsvListWriter object. Previously I was having this code where 'response' is HttpServletResponse.

```
CsvPreference preference = new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).useEncoder(new DefaultCsvEncoder()).build();
ICsvListWriter csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(response.getWriter(), preference);
```

This code is enhanced to this:

```
        ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(new byte[] { (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF });
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
        CsvPreference preference = new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).useEncoder(new DefaultCsvEncoder()).build();
        ICsvListWriter csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(writer, preference);
```

This fixed the issue and all of the superscript characters are now coming properly in generated CSV file without any junk characters. No mater whether I use actual superscript characters or their Unicode, this fix works.